# Ableton Live - viewing / editing CC sostenuto data

Tags: ableton, ableton-live

Hey guys, hope someone knows the answer here. Unable to locate anything in the docs about it. If I record a piano track complete with sustain pedal, and the. Later in the MIDI editor I move the notes data, the pedal CC doesn't come along. Same is true for quantizing. How can I, first of all, view the pedal CC data (there's no automation track created for it)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Ableton Live 7 User manual section 18.4:

> Choose "MIDI Ctrl" from a MIDI clip's
>   Device chooser and use the Control
>   chooser below it to select a specific
>   MIDI controller.

You can then select MIDI Ctrl | 64 - Hold Pedal or Show all Modulations and the sustain pedal data will show in the view.

Comment: Indeed! Why did I miss that?